# xmlhttprequest using promises inside a JS Revealing Module Pattern

Tags: javascript, module, promise, xmlhttprequest

I have an POST xmlhttprequest wrapped inside a Promise, which is inside an IIFE as I'm trying to use the Revealing Module Pattern. Basically I am successfully passing a value to my script which is in turn returning a response (the response is a list of NBA players from my db).  However I'm having some trouble making this response accessible in a separate IIFE (global controller module).

I have three Modules, a dataController one, a UIController one and a global one called Controller. I'd like the global controller to stitch together the UI and data ones in order to keep the UI and data ones completely separate.

I have left a couple of comments in the code starting with // ** which spell out what I'm trying to do.

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks!

```
// dataController module
const dataController = (() => {
    return {
        ajaxRequestLoadPlayer: (data) => {
            const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('POST', 'resources/loadPlayers.php', true);
                xhr.onload = () => {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                        resolve(response);
                    }
                    else {
                        reject(xhr.statusText);
                    }
                };
                xhr.send(data);
            });
           promise.then((response) => {
           // **if I console log the response here I can see the 
           // response  **
              return response;
           });
        },
    }
})();


// UI module
const UIController = (() => {
    // get the value of the select option
    // var playerLoadSelect = document.querySelector('#load-players-select');
    // var playerLoadSelectValue = playerLoadSelect.options[playerLoadSelect.selectedIndex].value;
    return {
        getPlayerFormInput: () => {
            return document.querySelector('#load-players-select').value;
        }
    }
})();


// controller module
const controller = ((dataCtrl, UICtrl) => {
    // add event listeners
    const setupEventListeners = () => {
        document.querySelector('.load-players').addEventListener("submit", loadPlayersForm);
    };
    // 1. get input value
    const loadPlayersForm = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const inputLoadPlayers = UICtrl.getPlayerFormInput();
        dataCtrl.ajaxRequestLoadPlayer(inputLoadPlayers);
    };
    // ** I would like to be able to access the response here so that I 
    // can use it with some functionality from the UIController above 
    return {
        init: () => {
            console.log('app started');
            setupEventListeners();
        }

    }
    // bridge the data from dataController to the ui update code
})(dataController, UIController);

controller.init();
```

Comment: You need to return the promise from `ajaxRequestLoadPlayer()` and use another `then()` when you call it. Right now that function has no `return`

Comment: Also easier to use more modern `fetch()` API than `XMLHttpRequest` and it is promise based

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl.  That worked, can't believe I didn't spot that!!  Please submit your comment as an answer and I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the promise from `ajaxRequestLoadPlayer()` and use another `then()`when you call it.

```
const dataController = (() => {
    return {
        ajaxRequestLoadPlayer: (data) => {
            // return promise
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('POST', 'resources/loadPlayers.php', true);
                xhr.onload = () => {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                        resolve(response);
                    }
                    else {
                        reject(xhr.statusText);
                    }
                };
                xhr.send(data);
            });           
        }
    }
})();


// usage    
dataController.ajaxRequestLoadPlayer(inputData).then(data=>{
   // consume the response data
   console.log(data)
})
```